# Rijndael 256-bit encryption/decryption throws an error

Tags: php, encryption

I've got the following class.

```
<?php
/**
 * Cypher Class
 */
class Cipher
{
    /**
     * SHA256 Encrypted Key
     * @var string
     */
    private $encryptedKey;
    /**
     * Initial vector
     *
     * Used to seed the encryption string
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $initVector;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param boolean|string $personalKey Holds the personal key to use in encryption
     */
    public function __construct($personalKey = false)
    {
        // $config = configuration::getInstance();
        if (false === $personalKey) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $key = $personalKey;
        }

        $this->encryptionKey = hash('sha256', $key, TRUE);
        $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
        $this->initVector = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    }
    /**
     * Encrypt a string
     * @param  mixed $input  Data to encrypt
     * @return string        Encrypted data
     */
    public function encrypt($input)
    {
        return array(
            'salt' => base64_encode($this->initVector),
            'encrypted_value' => base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $this->encryptionKey,
                $input,
                MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
                $this->initVector
        )));
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt string
     * @param  string $input Encrypted string we are going to decrypt
     * @param  string $salt Encrypted salt used to decrypt
     * @return string        Decrypted output
     */
    public function decrypt($input, $salt)
    {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->encryptionKey, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $salt));
    }
}
```

Both my IV and encrypted string are 16 bytes but for some reason PHP gives me the following error:

`Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in C:\xampp\htdocs\public\cipher\Cipher.php on line 58`

I am not really a star in encryptions and so I was wondering if one of you good people could help me out.

Comment: If you use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` for your iv size. Shouldn't you be using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` instead of `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` for encrypting and decrypting?

Comment: That does fix the problem, however I made both the iv and the cipher RIJNDAEL_256 and when I tested it on an external website and wanted to decrypt it, the website gave me an error saying ERROR: The $initVector is supposed to be 16 bytes in for CBC, CFB, NOFB, and OFB modes.

Comment: @tlenss Yes, is that possible or am I getting this thing all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an IV is related to the [*block size*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_%28cryptography%29) of the cipher. So whatever you choose as the block size must be used as the length of the IV.

Rijndael supports block sizes of 128, 160, 192, 224, and 256 bits. If you use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` then you are using the 128-bit block size (which matches AES). If you use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` then your block-size is twice as large.

So, you must decide which block size you want to use and ensure your code consistently refers to the same `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_*` constant.

I assume the website is giving you an error because it's expecting a 16-byte block size (as per AES).

Comment: So that would mean that I can only encrypt data which has the correct length?

Comment: @user3169577 With [cipher feedback mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29) (`MCRYPT_MODE_CFB`) you can encrypt data of any length.

Comment: I think I am mixing up the length and bytes story. How do i get the string to encrypt to be 16 bytes?

Comment: @user3169577 Your input string can be *any* length. Your IV value should be 16 bytes.

Comment: @user3169577 My apologies, I confused myself about what the PHP encryption constants mean. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Then could you tell me how to fix my class? Because I still haven't figured it out yet. If I for example use: '        $this->encryptionKey = hash('sha256', $key, TRUE);
     $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
     $this->initVector = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);' It does seem to work but the encrypted value just doesn't seem right. It is too short in my opinion.

Comment: @user3169577 The output size should be equal to the input size, in CFB mode. Is that not the case?

Comment: So if I input "hello", my output size should be 5? In that case, the problem is solved.

Comment: @user3169577 Yes, that would make sense if your string is interpreted as five ASCII bytes. CFB mode is a *stream cipher*, so the stream contents are XORed with your plaintext to produce ciphertext. Hence the output size always matches the input size.